# Creating a redirect from viewinvoice.php/?id=xx to viewinvoice./?=xx?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, file-extension

Hi I am updating a invoice system and we won't to redirect any http request using /client-area/viewinvoice.php/?id=xx to /client-area/viewinvoice/?id=xx basically removing the php extension. We can't remove them entirely as some pages still use them.

How do you do this via htaccess?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Updated main part.. Want to accomplish this via htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file for `.php` removal:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this didn't work. Does it matter that its a Wordpress install??

Comment: Yes it does matter and you should have mentioned it in your question. If it is WP then only 301 rule will work if that is placed before other WP rule.